# Restrict Google Places Autocomplete to return addresses only

Tags: google-places-api

```
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, { types: ['geocode'] });
```

returns streets and cities amongst other larger areas. Is it possible to restrict to streets only?

Comment: hmm, can you explain? Google places gives you list of places by defined radius and category. Please give an example what you tried yet

Answer (score 10):

This question is old, but I figured I'd add to it in case anyone else is having this issue. restricting types to 'address' unfortunately does not achieve the expected result, as routes are still included. Thus, what I decided to do is loop through the result and implement the following check:

`result.predictions[i].types.includes('street_address')`

Unfortunately, I was surprised to know that my own address was not being included, as it was returning the following types: `{ types: ['geocode', 'premise'] }`

Thus, I decided to start a counter, and any result that includes 'geocode' or 'route' in its types must include at least one other term to be included (whether that be 'street_address' or 'premise' or whatever. Thus, routes are excluded, and anything with a complete address will be included. It's not foolproof, but it works fairly well.

Loop through the result predictions, and implement the following:

```
if (result.predictions[i].types.includes('street_address')) {
    // Results that include 'street_address' should be included
    suggestions.push(result.predictions[i])
} else {
    // Results that don't include 'street_address' will go through the check
    var typeCounter = 0;
    if (result.predictions[i].types.includes('geocode')) {
        typeCounter++;
    }
    if (result.predictions[i].types.includes('route')) {
        typeCounter++;
    }
    if (result.predictions[i].types.length > typeCounter) {
        suggestions.push(result.predictions[i])
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a hook that we can place these conditions in?

Comment: Yeah this is the only way I was able to handle it as well, makes no sense, especially when you specifically tell Google `address`

Comment: Does this logic filter this address `Vilanova i la Geltrú, Spain` which does not have an address, number, and neither postal code?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is `{ types: ['address'] }`.

You can see this in action with this live sample: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete (use the "Addresses" radio button).

Comment: Using `{ types: ['address'] }` doesn't restrict results to be only those of type `street_address`. It also includes results of type `route`, which are roads without numbers.

Comment: is there a way to exclude `route` from the results?

Comment: @MaryKN this behavior is not intuitive. Is this on purpose? I have the same problem but the weirdest thing is that api works ok when server host is located in Europe and it does not work properly when the same code is placed in the machine located in the USA [google autocomplete issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65561058/google-autocomplete-api-showing-different-results-depending-on-deployment-region)

Comment: Google autocomplete does not guarantee always having a valid address containing street_number and postal_code. They suggest asking the user to type manually in these cases. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/225210134

Comment: Even geocode api does not filter full address, probably only when the user search by postalCode or using lat/long. This returns a Spain address unexpectedly `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=spain&result_type=street_address&location_type=ROOFTOP&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Comment: it does restrict it somewhat

Answer (score 1):

It seems we can resolve this reasonably well (at least for US addresses) by restricting types to `'street_address'` and `'premise'`, and by not performing the operation unless the first character of the input is a numeral (0-9).