# Google Places Autocomplete 'address' types also allows street only addresses

Tags: google-places-api

This question here basically asks the same question:

[Restrict Google Places Autocomplete to return addresses only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15071589/restrict-google-places-autocomplete-to-return-addresses-only)

But doesn't get the right answer.

If we look at the [official documentation examples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) they have an option to selected address type. However, on it, we can see that it will allow us to selected just streets:

[image]

Is there a way to make Places Autocomplete select real addresses only?

Comment: I'm running into the same problem and can't find a solution. What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is quite old, the search result is now somehow different but the fact that `address` type returns street addresses remains the same.

And to clarify things here, the API is **working as intended** when it returns street addresses.

`types=address` seems to be quite vague and what you need to do is to be more specific if you don't want street address to be included.

Here's a table for reference on the different types of restrictions for autocomplete from the [Place Types Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/supported_types#table3).

### Table 3: Type collections supported in Place Autocomplete requests

> The supported types are:
> `geocode` instructs the Place Autocomplete service to return only geocoding results, rather than business results. Generally, you use this request to disambiguate results where the location specified may be indeterminate.
> `address` instructs the Place Autocomplete service to return only geocoding results with a precise address. Generally, you use this request when you know the user will be looking for a fully specified address.
> `establishment` instructs the Place Autocomplete service to return only business results.
> `(regions)` type collection instructs the Places service to return any result matching the following types:
> `locality`
> `sublocality`
> `postal_code`
> `country`
> `administrative_area_level_1`
> `administrative_area_level_2` 
> `(cities)` type collection instructs the Places service to return results that match `locality` or `administrative_area_level_3`.

To further prove this, I tried using the [official documentation example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) for testing.

I tried searching real street address with both `types=address` and `types=geocode` and they return street addresses **as expected**.

With `address` type:
[image: address type]

With `geocode` type:
[image: geocode type]

Then I tried the `types=establishment` and it did not return any street addresses.

With `establishment` type:
[image: establishment type]

You can use any other `types` value apart from `types=establishment` like the `(cities)` and `(regions)`. As long as you are specific in your restrictions, things will be working fine. You can just put some toggle on your app to change restrictions just like on the [official docs example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) so that your end user could freely choose the restrictions. But it still depends on your use case.

Hope this helps.